# Override pager.phtml depending of page where it is used

Tags: magento2.3

because of the fact, that Magento2 is using the word "item" in all pager views, I have the problem because of the translation. In category view, I want to translate it as "Artikel", but in the user account list of orders, I do want to have the translation "Bestellungen" and not "Artikel".

Therefore, I thought to override the pager.phtnl template file depending on which site it is used. But no way I found on the internet worked.

Unfortunately, as with many other blocks the definition of a template file like:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="sales_order_item_pager" template="Magento_Theme::html/pagertest.phtml"/>
```

in sales_order.view.xml is not working. It is still using pager.phtml defined int Magento_Theme/templates/html

Does anybody have an idea how to get this working?

As I said doing it with my own module did not work. I tried a couple of suggestions.

Hopefully, somebody does have an answer.

By the way, I am working with Magento 2.3.3

Regards,
Chequille

Comment: is it typo: sales_order.view.xml?

Comment: yes, it is. of course sales_order_view.xml

Comment: Hi @Chequille, if you fix the problem, can you add the fix ? I am facing the same thing :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix that could work is to check the "full action name" in the `pager.phtml` file , by doing the following, for example for the product page:

```
<?php if ((string) $block->getRequest()->getFullActionName() === 'catalog_product_view') : ?>
// do you custom part
<?php else: ?>
// leave default magento
<?php endif ?>
```